# Rails application deployment issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, centos, passenger

I have a virtual private server (centos 5) with two IP addresses and one domain name associated with one of them.
I am trying to deploy a rails application through Apache + Passenger.
After usual installation and configuration I have this strange results:
1) if I browse and activate the controller actions using the secondary ip address everything works fine.
2) if I use the primary ip address or the domain name in the browser the result is "document not found"

Any possible hint/help?
Thanks
Antonio

---

Apache virtual host configuration:

VirtualHost *:80
ServerName www.mysitename.com
DocumentRoot /var/.../appname/public
Directory /var/......./appname/public
AllowOverride all
Options -Multiviews

there is no reference in the Apache httpd.conf file to the secondary ip address.

Thanks for the link to the useful documentation.

Antonio

Answer (score 1):

What is the apache configuration for the application?. The most possible reason for this behavior is the apache configuration is bound to the secondary ip address.

Refer [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#virtualhost) for changing the ip settings of apache.